# Input formats and strategies for Junit testing

Tags: performance, input, junit, build, testcase

My Java application have almost 800 Junit(5) test cases, my team is adding around 30 new cases a week. This component is a heart of the whole system, So every case needs lot of input data objects. Initially it is designed to read input data object (main object) from JSON files, Its like reading atleast 2/3 Jsons from @beforeClass method of every testclass. We are exepected to add more workflows this year and this does not look a viable solution to read the input data from Jsons. These many reads are causing performance issues as well and impacting the build time.

Can some one suggest alternate approaches to prepare the input data for Junit test cases.
We might not go with preparing manually in each test class as this will be a huge effort and one of the json in each test case is around 200 lines of data. (We use Gradle 6X and Junit 5).